# How to add a right button to a UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to add a refresh button to the top bar of a navigation controller with no success.

Here is the header:

```
@interface PropertyViewController : UINavigationController {

}
```

Here is how I am trying to add it:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Show" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                          target:self action:@selector(refreshPropertyList:)];      
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 362, accepted):

Try doing it in viewDidLoad. Generally you should defer anything you can until that point anyway, when a UIViewController is inited it still might be quite a while before it displays, no point in doing work early and tying up memory.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Show" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(refreshPropertyList:)];          
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;
  // exclude the following in ARC projects...
  [anotherButton release];
}
```

As to why it isn't working currently, I can't say with 100% certainty without seeing more code, but a lot of stuff happens between init and the view loading, and you may be doing something that causes the navigationItem to reset in between.

Comment: I you are doing this outside of the UINavigationController subclass, you would refer to it like this: someNavController.topLevelController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton

Comment: I was implementing the suggested solution and my app kept getting crashed until I realized that the @selector method name has to end in colon (:).

Comment: Even inside of a UINavigationContoller's viewDidLoad method, I had to call it like `self.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nextButton;`

Answer (score 38):

Try adding the button to the navigationItem of the view controller that is going to be pushed onto this `PropertyViewController` class you have created.

That is:

```
MainViewController *vc = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
[infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showInfo) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
vc.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoButton] autorelease];

PropertyViewController *navController = [[PropertyViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
```

Now, this infoButton that has been created programatically will show up in the navigation bar. The idea is that the navigation controller picks up its display information (title, buttons, etc) from the `UIViewController` that it is about to display. You don't actually add buttons and such directly to the `UINavigationController`.

Comment: Setting the rightBarButtonItem directly on the UINavigationController did not work for me (as proposed by Louis Gerbarg above). 

Instead setting the item directly on the UIViewController at hand like Adem suggests worked!

Comment: +1 for __"Try adding the button to the navigationItem of the view controller that is going to be pushed"__!

Answer (score 25):

It seems that some people (like me) may come here looking for how to add a navigation bar button in the Interface Builder. The answer below shows how to do it.

## Add a Navigation Controller to your Storyboard

Select your View Controller and then in the Xcode menu choose **Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller**.

[image]

Alternatively, you could add a `UINavigationBar` from the Object Library.

## Add a Bar Button Item

Drag a `UIBarButtonItem` from the Object Library to the top navigation bar.

[image]

It should look like this:

[image]

## Set the Attributes

You could double-click "Item" to change the text to something like "Refresh", but there is an actual icon for *Refresh* that you can use. Just select the Attributes Inspector for the `UIBarButtonItem` and for **System Item** choose **Refresh**.

[image]

That will give you the default Refresh icon.

[image]

## Add an IB Action

Control drag from the `UIBarButtonItem` to the View Controller to add an `@IBAction`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func refreshBarButtonItemTap(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        
        print("How refreshing!")
    }
    
}
```

That's it.

Comment: Sorry, I can't quite follow what you talking about. Try making a new question with an image illustrating what you are talking about. Then add a link to it here.

Comment: @Suragch, how can I do the same things with xib files instead of storyboards? , thanks

Comment: @CristianChaparroA. Usually xib files are for single views and the navigation bar (that hosts the bar button items) is for multiple views. I've never used an xib with bar button items. You could try asking a new question and then link to it here.

Answer (score 15):

There is a default system button for "Refresh":

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *refreshButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                            initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh
                            target:self action:@selector(refreshClicked:)] autorelease];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = refreshButton;

}

- (IBAction)refreshClicked:(id)sender {

}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use this:

Objective-C

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightSideOptionButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Right" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(rightSideOptionButtonClicked:)];          
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightSideOptionButton;
```

Swift

```
let rightSideOptionButton = UIBarButtonItem()
rightSideOptionButton.title = "Right"
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightSideOptionButton
```

Answer (score 6):

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    UIButton *btnRight = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnRight setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 44)];
    [btnRight setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnRight addTarget:self action:@selector(saveData) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *barBtnRight = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnRight];
    [barBtnRight setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[[self tabBarController] navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:barBtnRight];

}
```

Comment: Can anyone tell me is there any harm in doing it in ViewWillAppear instead of ViewDidLoad

Answer (score 6):

For swift 2 :

```
self.title = "Your Title"

var homeButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "LeftButtonTitle", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("yourMethod"))

var logButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "RigthButtonTitle", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("yourMethod"))

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = homeButton
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = logButton
```

Comment: I would recommend using the new swift2 selector: #selector(classname.functionname)

Answer (score 6):

You can try

```
self.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution in Swift (set options as needed):

```
var optionButton = UIBarButtonItem()
optionButton.title = "Settings"
//optionButton.action = something (put your action here)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = optionButton
```

Answer (score 4):

Why are you subclasses `UINavigationController`? There is no need to subclass it if all you need to do is add a button to it.

Set up a hierarchy with a `UINavigationController` at the top, and then in your root view controller's `viewDidLoad:` method: set up the button and attach it to the navigation item by calling

```
[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:myBarButtonItem];
```

Comment: That is a good question. What I am trying to do is actually a very common design pattern, which is a basic tab controller with a navigation controller for each tab. If there is a better way I am open for suggestions. Maybe I should ask that question too.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4 :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "tap me", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(onButtonTap))
}

@objc func onButtonTap() {
    print("you tapped me !?")
}
```

Comment: Just use navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem if you want right side button

Answer (score 2):

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 50)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIButton *settingsButton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[settingsButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_icon_png.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[settingsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(logOutClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[settingsButton setFrame:CGRectMake(40,5,32,32)];
[view addSubview:settingsButton];

UIButton *filterButton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[filterButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"filter.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[filterButton addTarget:self action:@selector(openActionSheet) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[filterButton setFrame:CGRectMake(80,5,32,32)];
[view addSubview:filterButton];



self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:view];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.It work for me.

*Navigation bar* and also added background image to right button.

```
 UIBarButtonItem *Savebtn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[[UIImage    
 imageNamed:@"bt_save.png"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] 
 style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(SaveButtonClicked)];
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=Savebtn;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(add:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{    
    [self setDetailViewNavigationBar];    
}
-(void)setDetailViewNavigationBar
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    [self setNavigationBarRightButton];
    [self setNavigationBarBackButton];    
}
-(void)setNavigationBarBackButton// using custom button 
{
   UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"  Back " style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(onClickLeftButton:)];          
   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton;    
}
- (void)onClickLeftButton:(id)sender 
{
   NSLog(@"onClickLeftButton");        
}
-(void)setNavigationBarRightButton
{

  UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Show" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(onClickrighttButton:)];          
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;   

}
- (void)onClickrighttButton:(id)sender 
{
   NSLog(@"onClickrighttButton");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refreshData)];



}

-(void)refreshData{
    progressHud= [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.navigationController.view animated:YES];
    [progressHud setLabelText:@"拼命加载中..."];
    [self loadNetwork];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add your barButtonItem in `- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated` method.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste this Objective-C code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self addRightBarButtonItem];
}
- (void) addRightBarButtonItem {
    UIButton *btnAddContact = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
    [btnAddContact addTarget:self action:@selector(addCustomerPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnAddContact];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
}

#pragma mark - UIButton
- (IBAction)addCustomerPressed:(id)sender {
// Your right button pressed event
}
```

Comment: I am trying to help

Answer (score 0):

This issue can occur if we delete the view controller or try to add new view controller inside the interface builder(main.storyboard). To fix this issue, it requires to add "Navigation Item" inside new view controller. Sometimes it happens that we create new view controller screen and it does not connect to "Navigation Item" automatically.

1. Go to the main.storyboard.
2. Select that new view Controller.
3. Go to the document outline.
4. Check view Controller contents.
5. If new view controller does not have a Navigation item then, copy Navigation item from previous View Controller and paste it into the new view controller.
6. save and clean the project.

Answer (score 0):

Also you are able to add multiple buttons using `rightBarButtonItems`

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    UIBarButtonItem *button1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"button 1" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(YOUR_METHOD1:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *button2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"button 2" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(YOUR_METHOD2:)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[button1, button2];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

@Artilheiro : If its a navigationbased project, u can create BaseViewController. All other view will inherit this BaseView. In BaseView u can define generic methods to add right button or to change left button text.

ex:

> @interface BaseController : UIViewController {
>
> }
>   - (void) setBackButtonCaption:(NSString *)caption;
>
> (void) setRightButtonCaption:(NSString *)caption selectot:(SEL )selector;
>
> @end
>   // In BaseView.M
>
> (void) setBackButtonCaption:(NSString *)caption
>   {

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];

backButton.title= caption;
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
[backButton release];
```

> }
>   - (void) setRightButtonCaption:(NSString *)caption selectot:(SEL )selector
>   {
>
> ```
>   UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
> ```

```
rightButton.title = caption;

rightButton.target= self;

[rightButton setAction:selector];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem= rightButton;

[rightButton release];
```

> }

And now in any custom view, implement this base view call the methods:

> @interface LoginView : BaseController {

In some method call base method as:

> SEL sel= @selector(switchToForgotPIN);
>
> [super setRightButtonCaption:@"Forgot PIN" selectot:sel];