# How to add a right button when specific UIViewController get loaded in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have two different `UIStorboard`s and I am using a `UINavigationController` to load the pages.

I have a total of three `UIViewController`s. Two of them are on the first `UIStoryboard` and the third one is on the second `UIStoryboard`.

1) Navigation controller

2) Main Controller

3) Value Screen Controller.

I want to add right button on navigation bar only when value screen controller get loaded. It should not be available on Main view controller.
I tried with this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219779/how-to-add-a-right-button-to-a-uinavigationcontroller) but not worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `UIViewController` has its own `UINavigationItem`s. So you can just add this right button in your Value Screen Controller by adding this line:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: <#T##UIBarButtonSystemItem#>, target: <#T##Any?#>, action: <#T##Selector?#>)
```

You can place it in `func viewDidLoad()` if you want it to be place as soon as the `UIViewController`'s view is loaded.